# Composer can't find mongodb extension

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

When executing composer require jenssegers/mongodb:

```
$ composer require jenssegers/mongodb
Using version ^3.0 for jenssegers/mongodb
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Problem 1

```
- jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.0 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
- jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.1 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
- jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.2 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
- mongodb/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- mongodb/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb ^3.0 -> satisfiable by
  ers/mongodb[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2].
```

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files

```
 - C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini
```

You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are us
P in CLI mode.

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

I am running Windows 7 and PHP 5.5.12 use mongodb 3.2 . I installed the mongodb extension (php_mongodb.dll in PHP ext/ folder), and I've updated php.ini with extension=php_mongodb.dll. Not sure what I've missed

Comment: Have you restarted Apache server after installing mongodb extension?

Comment: Yes  restarted  wamp server

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of drivers available at pecl

[image]

You need to install the **mongoDB database driver**. As you explained it looks like you have installed the mongoDB driver for PHP which is not correct

and you have to add php_mongo.dll in your php.ini

```
extension=php_mongo.dll
```

as explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows)

get the proper DLL from [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo)

You will get something like this in your phpinfo();

[image]

I hope this helps. Thanks,